# How can i update the progress bar in window application from another class?

Tags: c#

I have created one windows form, there i have a progress bar, i want to update the value of progress bar, from another class. I have written one function in my class on its execution, i want to see the progress in progress bar.

For Example:

1. The code written in forms .cs file:

```
 namespace UpdateProgressBar
{
    public partial class ProgressBarUdpate : Form
    {
        public ProgressBarUdpate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateDataProgress updt = new UpdateDataProgress();
            updt.ExecuteFucntion();
        }
    }
}
```

2. The code written in another class

```
namespace UpdateProgress
{
    public class UpdateDataProgress
    {
        public void ExecuteFucntion()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

My Expected output is when i call updt.ExecuteFucntion function it should update the progressbar values as per loop implemented in another class.

Comment: Events are a good way to go.

Comment: Can you please send some sample

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating GUI form Separate Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004331/updating-gui-form-separate-class)

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522762/update-ui-item-from-another-class-and-thread)

Comment: Actually i have two projects in same solution Windows Application and ClassLibrary, my another class is in ClassLibrary. Can i do the same in another library as well.

Comment: @stackoverflow I have added an answer, try it out. and let me know if it doesn't fit in your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Event` in such requirement.

**Logic:**

As your basic requirement is to update `Progressbar` (`UI`) based on current status of execution of a method (which is in class library)

You need to raise an event while executing `ExecuteFucntion()`. This Event will be Handled at `ProgressBarUdpate` form.

As you can see in code below, after creating an object of `UpdateDataProgress`, we are subscribing it's event by `updt.ExecutionDone += updt_ExecutionDone;`

Thus as soon as That event raised form `ExecuteFucntion()` it will call `updt_ExecutionDone` of `ProgressBarUdpate` where you can suerly update your progress bar.

Update your code as below.

```
    public partial class ProgressBarUdpate : Form
    {
        public ProgressBarUdpate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateDataProgress updt = new UpdateDataProgress();
            updt.ExecutionDone += updt_ExecutionDone;
            updt.ExecuteFucntion();
        }

        void updt_ExecutionDone(int value)
        {
            //Update your progress bar here as per value
        }
    }
```

and class `UpdateProgress`

```
    public delegate void ExceutionHandler(int value);
    public class UpdateDataProgress
    {
        public event ExceutionHandler ExecutionDone;
        public void ExecuteFucntion()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                //perform your logic

                //raise an event which will have current i 
                //      to indicate current state of execution
                //      use this event to update progress bar 

                if (ExecutionDone != null)
                    ExecutionDone(i);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Amit you are really genious

Comment: @stackoverflow you will see lot better people here. I'm glad that I could help you. Events and Delegates are really interesting topic. Invest your time and efforts on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Events, or simply:

1. Code in form:

   ```
   private void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       UpdateProgress.UpdateDataProgress updt = new UpdateProgress.UpdateDataProgress();
       updt.ExecuteFucntion(progressBar1);
   }
   ```
2. Code in class:

   ```
   public class UpdateDataProgress
   {
       public void ExecuteFucntion(System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progbar)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           {
               progbar.Value = i;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: But my class is in another classlibrary project in same solution. Does this work in this scenarios also